# server load spikes with unknown postgres process

Tags: postgresql

Linux machine got infected by a malware. After some analysis we found .sh file under postgres home and postgres crontab entry.

Below are the steps we performed :

1. Killed the process.
2. Removed .systemd-service.sh file and /var/spool/cron/postgres entries.

But after some time interval process is coming back with same.

Help us to find out the solution from this malware.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't described fixing the underlying problem that lead to the hack (likely weak password on SQL user super-user account, combined with letting any random IP connect as super-user in the first place).  So why wouldn't you just get hacked again?

Answer (score 0):

- `pg_dumpall` the database
- wipe the machine
- reinstall the operating system and PostgreSQL
- restore the dump
- change all operating system and PostgreSQL passwords to good ones

Comment: Plus: disallow remote superuser access